# use data stored in android sqlite database as input to weka

Tags: android, sqlite, jdbc, weka

I am not sure if anyone has ever tried this. I am currently storing attributes in a sqlite database on android. What I want to do next is to retrieve these data and apply Machine learning algorithms implemented by Weka. Weka can indeed take data from databases using JDBC. But can this be done with android? The SQLite database in android doesn't seem to be a normal SQLite databse.

I have read this http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+connect+to+a+database%3F, but it doesn;t help much.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a ready implementation for Weka to read the data from sqlite on Android, because the helper class mainly depend on JDBC which is not available for android.

I can think of two options to achieve this:

- Query the sqlite database on Android and create Weka training instances programatically on the fly. This solution might be more suitable for online training and when you have large dataset.
- Export the training data from sqlite as csv file and pass the file to Weka for training.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that WEKA won't work on Android without changes. J48, for example, requires the java.lang.Cloneable interface, which is not available in Android.

This is a weka port to android project [here](https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android).
Hope it will help you.